# mongodb data model for monitoring/logging application with 10'000 loggers

Tags: mongodb, database-design, data-modeling

I'm defining the data model for a monitoring/logging application with MongoDB storage. As I'm new to MongoDB I would appreciate some advice from you.

The application's writes:

I have 10'000 loggers, for each logger I have:

- static data that does not change over time (a few kilobytes per logger)
- data I must log that comes in continuously every few seconds from each logger

the volume of the data is:

- 1 MB or 9000 messages a day per logger

elimination pattern:

- the data must be deleted automatically by the system 30 days after creation
- 60% of the data gets fetched by other systems before 30 days and will be deleted on fetch

the application's reads:

- if the data gets read, than all messages at once which causes them to be deleted from the system
- the data gets read soonest 1 hour and latest 30 days after creation. average is 14 days.

averages:

- I calculated that the mean time for data storage is 14 days which gives 40'000 messages or 13MB per logger
- the total amount of data stored in the db on average is 130GB

My Questions:

- What data model would you use?
- How many shards would you use?

I considered the following data models:

- embedded: a document per logger with an array of messages; bad because of disk relocation when document grows
- a capped collection per logger; bad because of big disk usage and imprecise time till the data gets overwritten
- a collection of loggers for static data plus a collection per logger for messages using TTL feature; are 10'000 collections ok?
- a collection of loggers for static data plus a single collection for all messages using TTL and compound index including vehicle and messageId; isn't that collection really big?
- a collection of loggers for static data including a pre allocated array with id references plus a collection for all messages with indexed id; too complicated?

You are free to propose other data models

Answer (score 1):

Your fourth option sounds best.  No worries on how big the collection is, you just need to ensure that you have a proper shard key picked.

The key to picking a good shard in this case will depend on how the messages are actually found.  Do you have a message id and the external application that reads them just queries for an id?  Or are you doing a full text search on the messages?  Does the external app know the logger & datetime that the message was created?

Considerations:

- If you make the logger your shard key then you'll end up with chunks that are too big to split
- If you make the datetime your shard key then you'll end up with poor distribution due to your share key
- If the external application is going to be searching by message id then make the hashed message id your shard key.  That will ensure good distribution and movable chunks

Don't worry about having a separate collection for the static data.

Like I said, the key to designing this is clarifying how, exactly, the log messages are found by the external system.

Comment: the messages get fetched on per logger basis all at once. The only thing the external app puts in the query is the loggers id. The db responds with all the messages for this logger. The loggers id is part of every message.

Comment: The mongodb manual says that having a large number of collections can be beneficial: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#large-number-of-collections
couldn't that be my case?

Comment: You can get around collection-wide locks and increase throughput by having lots of collections; your tradeoff is more space overhead.  At this point you'll probably want to do some testing, as you should when you're deciding on any architecture.  Set things up both ways and throw a production load at it.  See which one falls over.   A lot will depend on your hardware.

Comment: If you decide to go the sharded route then you'll have to go scatter-gather.  As I mentioned, using the logger ID as the shard key will result in too-big chunks, so you can use something like the hash of the created date and the ensure that there's an index on logger id